# how to extract substring from a undefined length of string?

Tags: c#, string

Substring these string:-

```
1. ZZ111122
2. ZZZZ222111
3. ZZZZZZZ333
4. ZZZ111333
```

I have these kind of strings. This value is always starting with Z. And after Z its always either 1 or 2 or 3. But i dont know the number of Zs in the string. So how can i extract all Z from the string

Comment: By extract do you perhaps mean "remove"?

Comment: What is the expected result? Line 1 for example: you want a string like "ZZ"? or may be "111122"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String test = "ZZ111122";
String zOnly = test.Substring(0, test.IndexOfAny("123".ToCharArray()));
```

Take advantage of `IndexOfAny()`. I am assuming you want only Z's left over ("extract all Z from the string").

Comment: Be careful: while `IndexOf` searchs for a single character within text, `IndexOfAny` searchs for multiple characters within the text, which is surely less performative. Although very useful several times, it isn't necessary for the OP needs.

Comment: @ErickPetru: True, but the OP didn't specify any performance requirements.

Comment: Sure, then the OP chooses the answer with poor performance just because of it. In fact, also chooses the answer that isn't fully working, since your `IndexOfAny` is a string method, so the code must be: `String zOnly = test.Substring(0, test.IndexOfAny("123".ToCharArray()));`. Finally, the accepted answer has only **0** votes. What about reading it: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Apparently choosing the best answer has not been a common practice here on StackOverflow. In a few days here I have already figured it out. Congratulations on your reading appointment!

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I understood right. If you have "ZZZZ222111" and want only "222111", do it:

```
string test = "ZZZZ222111";
test = test.Substring(test.LastIndexOf("Z") + 1);
```

If you want only "ZZZZ", do it:

```
string test = "ZZZZ222111";
test = test.Substring(0, test.LastIndexOf("Z"));
```

Both ways are very simple. No need of loops or regular expressions.

Comment: +1 For the more complete and more easy solution at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're going to want to use [regular expressions](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet) for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) function:

```
ZeroZValue = stringValue.Trim('Z');
```

Comment: `Trim()` removes characters both from the beginning and end of the string. I would suggest `TrimStart()` instead.

Comment: @svick: He has clearly declared that he does not have but 1, 2 or 3 after the z letters ..

Comment: yeah, but using `TrimStart()` makes the intent clearer and is probably going to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

This is not difficult. I recommend processing the text line by line.

You can loop the string character by character. You can use regular expressions. Or you could use my [sscanf() replacement class for C#](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net).

Answer (score 0):

```
int start = someString.IndexOf("Z");
int end = someString.LastIndexOf("Z");
someString.Substring(start , end - start);
```